# Short if this else that in PHP?

Tags: php

I was searching for some shorthand if/else code, but unlike `$var ? $a : $b` it doesn't need an 'else'-like returned value. What I want would be basically this, but shorter:

```
$myVariable = "abc";
echo $myVariable ? $myVariable : "hello";
echo $myVariable ? "hello" : $myVariable;
```

I'm kind of used to do such a thing in Lua, which goes like:

```lua
local myVariable = "abc"

-- In case myVariable is false, print "hello". Otherwise it prints "abc"
print ( myVariable or "hello" )

 -- In case myVariable does have something (So, true) print "goodday."
print ( myVariable and "goodday" )
```

So I wondered, does PHP have the functionality to do such a thing?
Thanks.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. What do you want to happen? What have you tried that failed?

Comment: you mean like `if($myVariable)echo $myVariable ;`

Comment: In PHP shortest method is trinary operator '?:', that you already know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$myVariable ? $myVariable : "";
```

is equivalent to:

```
$myVariable ?: "";
```

PS: You should be aware that PHP does type juggling here. This is basically the same as:

```
if ($myVariable == TRUE) ...
```

If `$myVariable` happens to be a string like `0`, it will evaluate to false. However `00` will evaluate to true. I've found this not so useful as it appears to be. In many cases you will need to check if `$myVariable` is set first, or do a type comparison and make sure the variable is boolean...

Comment: That should be fine. There's somewhat of type checking in another function before these variables exist. Other than that, this is for some public script. I expect my co-workers to follow the rules and stick to the function usage.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use ternar operator's else, you can allways do something like:

```
$myVariable = "abc";
echo $myVariable ? $myVariable : "";
```

Which prints nothing when not $myVariable

Comment: I think the question was for the shorter syntax.

Comment: That's exactly what I got in my example >_>

Comment: I dont think it is exactly your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo (!empty($myVariable)) ? $myVariable : "hello";
```

or

```
echo (isset($myVariable)) ? $myVariable : "hello";
```

Since PHP is a weak-typed language, `$myVariable` containing `0` or `""`, may be treated as [false](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).
And you should check if the variable exist, or at least, make sure that it is string.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.3 you can do:

```
echo $myVariable ?: "hello";
```

Witch is equal to:

```
echo $myVariable ? $myVariable : "hello";
```

I think second option is not possible.

Comment: Sounds great. We're using PHP 5.4 here so that's all fine. Seems like a nice option to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$myVariable = "abc";
echo $myVariable ? : "hello";
```

It doesn't get any shorter than the above in PHP. That should check that $myVariable has a value and print that out, otherwise print out "hello"

Answer (score 0):

All do the same. Even shorter in php 7

```
$var = $var ?? $var;
```