# PHP have syntax like this: $expr= $a || $b

Tags: php

In javascript I can do:

```
$a= $b || $c
```

if $b is null or empty then $a=$c, else $a=$b.

there is somthing like that in php?

i tried:

```
$a=$b && $c
```

but I get $a=true or false, not the value of $b or $c.

Comment: `$a = empty($b) ? $c : $b;`

Comment: Is `$b` guaranteed to *exist*?

Comment: Note that, in JavaScript, `b || c` evaluates to `b` if it is truthy, or `c` if `b` is falsy; this covers more cases than "`b` is null or empty"

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935682/short-if-this-else-that-in-php/14935733#14935733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because by applying the "||" operator on those parameters you are making a logical expression which it's answer is true/false.

you can use:

```
$a = $b?$b:$c;
```

As of PHP 5.3 you can use a shorten expression:

```
$a = $b?:$c;
```

which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Python also has this, but in PHP logical operators return a boolean.

You can `$b ? $b : $c`

Or you can replace the `$b` condition with `!empty($b)`, `!is_null($b)`, etc... but first make sure you understand [what they do](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (for example `0` and `"0"` are both empty and that's not necessary what you want). My guess is that you need `(isset($b) && $b !== "")`.

Comment: Since PHP 5.3: `$b ?: $c`

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

```
$a = (empty($b) ? $c : $b)
```

Long version:

```
if (empty($b)
    $a = $c;
else
    $a = $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = !empty($b) ? $b : $c;
```

Maybe isn't exactly what you are looking for, but the ternary conditional would do that (it's common in most languages)

condition ? case true : case false ;

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = null;
$b = 15;
$c = $a || $c = $b;
var_dump($c);
$c = $a or $c = $b;
var_dump($c);
```

Comment: if left part == false (false, null, 0 or some else) OR exec right part (sorry my english). it's can be usefull when u try connect to Database: $a = DB::connect() or die("can't connect to db");